# JQueryMobile data send

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me with this ..

I am trying to send data from Page1 to Page2 and display it in Page2. If I accomplish this task I can use the same implementation in my project. Here is my code in Page1.

Text Input:
             
            

              Submit

when submit button is clicked I am able to show the "SecondFrom.aspx". How can I get the value entered in "name" textbox in Page 1 to display in Page2 ...????

In Page2 I would like to call .ajax to webservice with this data(name value) and create listView basd on name value. I know to call the ajax function..but I can't get the value from page1.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

if the textbox is within a from and the submit button submits the form to your Page2 then in the code behind you can access the form values

```
string name = Request.QueryString["name"];
string name = Request.Form["name"]; // for POSTed form
```